# MySQL cloud9 external Connection info

Tags: cloud9-ide

how I can connect to MySQL server from mysqlworkbrench tool, I can't to find IP to connect. I tried to get $IP from console, but it returned 0.0.0.0

Comment: Ask [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for some reason you needed the external IP address of the machine you're working on, from one of the console windows run - curl -s checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'

Answer (score 0):

Cloud typically uses 127.0.0.1 as the workspace's IP address.